# 2D orientation test barycentric coordinates

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangular, robust

If I have an ordered 3-tuple of points in integer barycentric coordinates,
how do I test orientation on them?
(I want to know if the points are collinear, form a left turn or a right turn)

The "algorithm" has to be quite robust so I don't want to convert the coordinates to cartesians.

For cartesians, there is a very nice way to determine this using only multiplication and addition:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html

There is a similar way to find out if three points are collinear here,
but I don't know if I can use it for this application:
http://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-short.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the last paper says, for CCW base triangle ABC signed area for PQR is positive for CCW order (footnote at page 1), so triplet P, Q, R makes left turn if determinant

```
 x1  y1  z1
 x2  y2  z2
 x3  y3  z3
```

has positive value (theorem 10), and points are collinear for zero determinant

Comment: No, it is not needed for this test.

Comment: what if all z values are zero? You can express all coordinates like that and the determinant would be 0, even if they are not collinear. The question was more like if there is another chance to prevent this test from failing.

Comment: Z value is zero for points on the edge AB (more thoroughly - on the line containing this edge). All z values might be zero only in the case when all three points lie **on the the same edge** of base triangle - so they are collinear. No failing.